# BizTalk 2016 SharePoint Adapter - Force Use of Port 443

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, csom, biztalk-2016

I'm trying to integrate a BizTalk 2016 FP3 application with a SharePoint 2013 site that is available only over port 443 / https.

I would like to use a dynamic send port, the new(ish) adapter and the CSOM.

I have an orchestration with a logical one-way send port called "SendToSp". Within the orchestration I have an expression shape containing the following:

```
SendToSp(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "wss://collaboration.xxx.co.uk/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/Lists/BizTalkTestList/"
```

Following this, there's a construct message shape, containing and assignment shape where the message to send is created and the context properties assigned as follows:

```
msgNvpToSp(xxx.Integration.Common.Schemas.PropertySchema.FormType) = "DynamicSharePointSend";
msgNvpToSp(WSS.ConfigPropertiesXml) = "<ConfigPropertiesXml><PropertyName1>Title</PropertyName1><PropertySource1>This comes from received xml msg</PropertySource1></ConfigPropertiesXml>";  
msgNvpToSp(WSS.ConfigAdapterWSPort) = 443;
msgNvpToSp(WSS.ConfigOverwrite) = "no";
msgNvpToSp(WSS.ConfigUseClientOM) = "yes";
```

My problem is, when BizTalk sends the message I get a "Transmission Failure" with the following description:

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException] Cannot contact site at the specified URL http://collaboration.xxx.co.uk:80/.
>
> This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive location or send port with URI wss://collaboration.xxx.co.uk:80/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/Lists/BizTalkTestList/.
>
> Windows SharePoint Services adapter event ID: 12310

If I check the context properties of the suspended message then I see the following:

[image]

Notice how the value for "OutboundTransportLocation" property includes port 443.

Any ideas why it's insisting on sending on port 80 even when I've told it to use 443?

Answer (score 0):

In the address, you have to put "wss**s**://collaboration.xxx.co.uk/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/Lists/BizTalkTestList/", then https and port 443 will be used.